# How to get an integer value from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am having this weird issue. NSDictionary is not returning the correct integer value.

JSON response code from server.

```
{
"status":"ok",
"error_code":0,
"data" : [],
"msg":"everything is working!"
}
```

The JSON is being converted to a NSDictionary.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error: &error];
```

I access the NSDictionary value using the following code.

```
int error_code = (int)[jsonDict valueForKey:@"error_code"]
NSLog(@"%i", error_code);
The log outputs the following: 143005344
```

I've even tried objectForKey and I get the same response.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes it outputs the pointer of the value and that's why you see this log output.

You cannot cast the pointer to an integer and expect the value.

```
int error_code = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"error_code"] integerValue];
```

or if you want to use modern objective-c

```
int error_code = [jsonDict[@"error_code"] integerValue];
```

Comment: You should use `int` and `intValue`, or else `NSInteger` and `integerValue`—but you shouldn’t mix them without an explicit cast.

Comment: thanks it helped me a lot. I could NSLog all the key / value pairs correctly, but trying to store the Int value I also received a pointer. This answer helped me quite a bit!

Comment: what kind of construct is this ? Is it another way of casting in Objective-C?

Answer (score 11):

Numbers are stored as [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances in plist/json dictionaries. Try calling one of `NSNumber`'s getters like `intValue`:

```
int error_code = [jsonDict[@"error_code"] intValue];
```

Note also the new subscripting syntax for dictionaries.